# Can Buzz Lightyear really fly?

Tags: toy-story

I saw at the end of the first *Toy Story* movie that Buzz Lightyear could fly, even though he wasn't able to at first. Why is this?

Could Buzz fly all along or not?

Comment: "this isn't flying...this is falling. With style." - Buzz

Answer (score 7):

He can glide to an extent. At the end of the movie, he and Woody used Sid's rocket as a booster to get some altitude, and then Buzz spread his wings to detach from the rocket and glide to the car and safety.

Comment: so; in that meaning; (buzz) (not woody) (or sid) so buzz; can glide rather; (than fly). assuming; (this is ) correct; right?

Comment: @Mintvbz All the random brackets and semicolons make it really hard to tell what your comment is meant to say. Please try and make sure you're using proper grammar.

Comment: Gliding may be considered a form of flying. Gliding in its most basic definition is to move using air currents, although one can glide through the air, on water, or on land. Flying is to move through the air. In this case, Buzz’s gliding _is_ flying. He always had this capability to fly.

Answer (score 0):

The federal Aviation Administration (FAA) (in the USA, and most if not all other Civil Aeronautic Authorities (CAA)) considers gliders to be equivalent in many ways to powered aircraft, most importantly in terms of requiring training and licensing of pilots.

In that respect, yes, Buzz can "fly" because he can "glide". Just as a human piloted glider must be towed into the sky then can fly for hours in the hands of a skilled pilot, one can assume that Buzz, with practice, could fly for hours after being boosted into the sky by Sid's rocket.